# How to move position up by one when name is deleted

Tags: java, arrays, loops, input

```
    public void deleteQueue() {       
    int position;
    PassengerQueue();
    System.out.println("Enter Queue Position which you want to delete a customer from: ");
    position = input.nextInt();
    qitems[position] = "empty";
    System.out.println("");

    for (int look = front; look < end; look++) {
        if (qitems[look].equals("empty")) {
            System.out.println(look + ". " + qitems[look]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(look + ". " + qitems[look]);
        }
    }
```

What i am trying to do is, if a user enters a name, it will be put in position 0, if the user enters another name, it will put in posiiton 1 so 0 - bob, 1 - jon. what i want it to do is if bob position 0 gets deleted, it will change jons position from 1 to 0.

Comment: why not using a List instead?

Comment: are any of these answers acceptable @A97?

Comment: most dont work, e.g 0: bob, 1:joe., if the user deletes bob,need something which will make the loop restart so it will print 0:joe

Answer (score 2):

by using `List` there is no need to shift all the elements after delete, but if it's force to use `array` you can shift all in a simple loop:

```
public void deleteQueue() {       
    int position;
    PassengerQueue();
    System.out.println("Enter Queue Position which you want to delete a customer from: ");
    position = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("");

    for (int i = position; i < qitems.length-1; i++) {
        qitems[i] = qitems[i+1];
    }
    qitems[qitems.length] = null;
}
```

Comment: Simple enough.. but as you mentioned, a list is way better in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to figure out how to do an operation like this on a "low-level" object like a String array, you can always ask:

Is there a "higher-level" Java class that already exists that does the same thing?

In this case the answer is yes, there are a few... but I'm assuming you're not allowed to use them directly.

However, you can still look at their source code to see how they do exactly the same thing you're trying to do.

For example, in Android Studio, you can create a new ArrayList object... or just type "ArrayList," then right-click it... and select "go to Declaraction."

This will take you to the source code for the class you clicked on.

This is how the Android source code for ArrayList does a remove():

```
public E remove(int index) {
    if (index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));

    modCount++;
    E oldValue = (E) elementData[index];

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work

    return oldValue;
}
```

You can see this is similar to Hamid's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either loop through the array rearranging the positions or simply use some class that already does this for you, [such as a linked list for example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), which implements the remove(int index) method.

Answer (score -1):

Put

```
qitems[position-1] = qitems[position]
```

inside of a for loop to cycle through each index that is after the one deleted.